# angular2: add error class to invalid input

Tags: angular

I have a form created with formbuilder in my SettingsComponent:

```
constructor(){
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'firstname': ['', Validators.required],
        'lastname': ['', Validators.required],
        'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator])]
    });
}
```

what I want to do now is add a class to my input when the value is not valid. But when I do this:

```
<label class="input" [ngClass]="{'state-error': lastname.valid}">
    <input ngControl="lastname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastname" id="lastname" #lastname="ngForm"/>
</label>
<small [hidden]="lastname.valid" class="form-required-field-info">this is a required field</small>
```

this produces the following error:

> Expression '{'state-error': lastname.valid} in SettingsComponent@60:57' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null'. Current value: 'false'

Link to demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/WvycldydiuMsi8HwgIYc

What am I missing? Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not caused by `lastname.valid` but by changing the model in `ngAfterViewInit()` Angular doesn't like the model being changed in lifecycle callbacks.

If you change

```ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.user = {'lastname': 'test'};
  }
```

to

```ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.user = {'lastname': 'test'});
  }
```

the error is gone. No need to change the view template.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/W8CEGiw8V5H4Nn72NQUY?p=preview)

Comment: thank you. I tried that but that returns the same error

Comment: Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: this is the first time I tried this, hope it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/WvycldydiuMsi8HwgIYc

Comment: Seems to work https://plnkr.co/edit/W8CEGiw8V5H4Nn72NQUY?p=preview the way I explained in my answer.

Comment: but when I run that I still get the error in my console

Comment: You are right. I tried a few times and didn't get any errors but now when I reopen I get them as well. I'll have another look.

Comment: why setTimeout? what I actually do there is do a GET request to fetch data from a json -> does that still require a setTimeout?

Comment: `setTimeout` is to schedule the task for later execution. It is added to the event queue and done when the previously scheduled tasks are completed. This ensures Angulars change detection is done before our code is executed. If you run some async code than this is added to the event queue for later execution anyway and `setTimeout` is **not** required in this case.

Comment: then the problem is something else. I tried to update the plunker but I cannot get my GET request to work ...

Comment: `.subscribe()` is missing. Without it an observable won't do anything because it's lazy.

Comment: one more related question: how would I access individual errors for a form field? I tried something like userForm.controls['lastname'].errors.required but that doesn't work of course

Comment: After the change shown in my answer `lastname.valid` was working fine, so it should be fine for `errors` as well (`lastname.errors`). What do you mean "but that doesn't work of course? As far as I remember this is how it should work. I'll check the Plunker again.

Comment: I just saw, if there is no error `lastname.errors` is `null` and then `lastname.errors.required` throws. Just use `lastname.errors?.required` instead to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you are not running in dev mode. In dev mode, such errors are encountered when change detection kicks in immediately after ngViewInit. (Even though this is the expected behavior in Dev Mode, to identify possible errors in out code, but there is a bug open [#6005](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005))

So for now, enable prod mode, where in change detection automatically kicks in every time a change happens.

Comment: That's a bad advice. `devMode` exists for a purpose and it's to find bugs that make change detection inefficient.

Comment: I see. The link is a perfect fit to the question. Disabling `devMode` is still the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

seems like I found the solution (I think). What I need to do is manually detect changes. So I import ChangeDetectorRef from angular/core, inject it in the constructor and then, after importing the form data, I do this:

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```